# owl-carousel css not loading in production rails app

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, heroku, webpack, owl-carousel

As you can see below in the development environment the css for owl carousel is picked up and loaded. However, in production its not being picked up.

**Development Sources**

[image: development sources picture]

**Production Sources**
[image: production sources picture]

**Owl Carousel Node Module**
[image: node modeul picture]

***app/javascript/packs/application.js***

```
require("@rails/ujs").start()
require("turbolinks").start()
require("@rails/activestorage").start()
require("channels")
require("trix")
require("@rails/actiontext")

import 'owl.carousel/dist/assets/owl.carousel.css';
import 'owl.carousel';

import JQuery from 'jquery';
window.$ = window.JQuery = JQuery;
```

***/package.json***

```
{
  "name": "MangaReviews",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@rails/actioncable": "^6.0.0",
    "@rails/actiontext": "^6.0.3-2",
    "@rails/activestorage": "^6.0.0",
    "@rails/ujs": "^6.0.0",
    "@rails/webpacker": "4.2.2",
    "jquery": "^3.5.1",
    "owl.carousel": "^2.3.4",
    "trix": "^1.2.0",
    "turbolinks": "^5.2.0"
  },
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "devDependencies": {
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.0"
  }
}
```

***config/webpack/environment.js***

```
const { environment } = require('@rails/webpacker')

const webpack = require('webpack')

environment.plugins.prepend('Provide',
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        $: 'jquery',
        jQuery: 'jquery',
        'window.jQuery': 'jquery'
    })
)

module.exports = environment
```

**Deployment Log rake asset:precompile**
[image: deploy log picture]

Comment: rename stylesheet_link_tag in to stylesheet_pack_tag in order to work in production

Answer (score 0):

i found the solution. I guess when you are loading css through webpack you have to use

```
<%= stylesheet_pack_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
```

I added this in my application.html.erb and it began working.